# How to return dropdown value of category attribute in magento

Tags: php, magento

I add a custom dropdown category attribute labeled as 'custom_filter', and it has only two value, 'yes' and 'no'. How can I get the value of it in .phtml file?

I have tried the code like

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($store_id)->getAttribute('custom_filter');
```

or

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->getAttributes('custom_filter');
```

I know that these are incorrect, so pls give some hints of it. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
echo $category->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getFrontend()->getValue($category);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! But it always return no, even I set it as Yes.